How to use Activity Indicator in AppShell.xaml with TabBar?
I am using a logout buttom in Shell.TitleView in AppShell.xaml
Now I want to show an activity indicator in the middle of the screen when clicked on logout, irrespective of which tab I am in.
How to incorporate the UI for activity indicator in AppShell.xaml with TabBar in it.
I tried:
AppShell.xaml
<ShellContent IsVisible="{Binding ShowIndicator}" Route="LoaderOverlay">
    <local1:LoaderOverlay/>
</ShellContent>

LoaderOverlay.xaml
<Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" Color="White" />
        <Label Text="Loading..." TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid
</Grid>

Note-I have my logout command in respective viewmodel binded to AppShell.xaml.cs
and on that command i am making ShowIndicator true

https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/netmaui-overlay-playground/tree/main/src/DrasticOverlay/Overlays/Loading
